# Python: How to code 2 different inputs

Tags: python, loops, user-input

I'm trying to make a game to learn how to code with python. I've reached a part where I want a *while* loop to keep asking for input if the user input is not valid. But I also want two different inputs to give different outputs. However, I've coded it so that any user input is not valid.

```
action4 = input()
while action4 != ("left") or action4 != ("right"):                           
    print ("Left or right?")
    action4 = input()
if action4 == ("left"):
    print ("You turn left and proceed down this hallway")
    left = True
elif action4 == ("right"):
    print ("You turn right and proceed down this hallway")
    left = False
```

I'm trying to get it so that both `left` and `right` are both valid outputs. But keep the *while* loop so that if any other input is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let us consider the conditional in the while loop:

```
action4 != ("left") or action4 != ("right")
```

we need this to evaluate as False to break out of the while loop, so what values would make this False? We can break the conditional down like this:

```
action4 = ...
cond1 = action4 != ("left")
cond2 = action4 != ("right")
result = cond1 or cond2
print(cond1,cond2,result)
```

so what if `action4 = "left"`? Well then `cond1 -> False` but `cond2 -> True` so because one of them is True, `cond1 or cond2` is True.

what if `action4 = "right"`? Well then `cond1 -> True` but `cond2 -> False` so because one of them is True, `cond1 or cond2` is True.

I think what you need to change is the `or` to `and`, so if action4 is not *either* of left or right then it will break:

```
while action4 != ("left") and action4 != ("right"):
```

or you can use the `not in` operator:

```
while action4 not in ("left","right"):
```

which is a bit easier to understand.